# Range.Text property giving weird results when retrieving values from a table in Microsoft word to use in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to retrieve data from a table that was created in Microsoft word (which has only one table) so that I can reuse the word document and save each instance as a PDF file. OK, so I have reached as far as to open the word file from VB.net, but I got stuck when I tried to index a value from the table.

When I run this code the message box shows an ASCII like looking character for the cell referenced at cell(3,1), but is actually a numeric value from the table in MS word.

in fact it does not work with any possible cell index.

Can any one help me with referencing the table values properly?

It would be highly appreciated, thanks.

'''

```
Private Sub CateringApp_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document

    Try
        oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        oWord.Visible = True
        oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(Application.StartupPath & "\SampleInvoice.docx")

        'line of code that shows weird results when invoked
        MessageBox.Show(oDoc.Tables.Item(1).Cell(3, 1).Range.Text)

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

'''

Comment: Remember: zero indexing! Do you maybe want position (0,2)?

Comment: well, i tried Cell(0,2 ) and it gave the same result.

Comment: You should edit the question to include that information.

Comment: Also, zero indexing would apply to the `Tables` collection, too. You probably want `oDoc.Tables.Item(0)`

Comment: with item(0) it gave "the requested index of the collection does not exist" error.

Comment: It's shouldn't be possible in .Net to have an `Item(1)` if you don't also have an `Item(0)`

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the line that gave weird results:

```
 MessageBox.Show(oDoc.Tables.Item(1).Cell(3, 1).Range.Text)
```

Gave weird results because the item(1) index should really be item(2).
items usually start indexing at 1 and not 0, but for some reason the MS word doc interprets anther control as Item(1), so that the table becomes item(2).